# My fullcalendar background color is not working on listDay or listWeek but works on month

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

In my ajax data for fullcalendar I have a field called backgroundc that denotes a change to red for the background color for an event.  This works perfectly in the default month view but not in the listDay or listWeek veiw even thought when inspecting the code the tr class fc-list-item does show an attribute for background-color as red for these events. I also have a qtip event running which works across all views.  I am running fullcalendar 3.0.1
Here is my code for this calendar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#divcalander").fullCalendar({
                aspectRatio: 1.6,       
                header:{
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,listWeek,listDay,listMonth'
                },
                views:{
                    month:{
                        titleFormat: '[MCH In-Sevices for ]'+'MMMM YYYY'
                    },
                    listWeek:{buttonText: 'List Week'},
                    listDay:{buttonText: 'List Day'},
                    month:{buttonText: 'Month'},
                    listMonth:{buttonText: 'List Month'}
                },
                theme: true,
                events:{
                    url:'populateinservicecal.php',
                    type:"get",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{startParam:'startDate',endParam:'endDate'}        
                },
                eventRender:function(event,element){
                    element.qtip({
                        content:
                            {text:"Location: "+event.locationdescr,
                            title:event.title},
                         position: {
                            my: 'bottom left',
                         style:{
                            classes: 'qtip-cream'
                         }
                        }                                 
                    })
                    if(event.backgroundc=="Red"){
                        element.css('background-color','Red')
                    }
                                                
                },
                eventLimit: false,
                timeFormat: 'h:mmt'
            })
        })
    </script>
    
    
    
    <title>HRS Class Sessions</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div style=" margin: auto; width: 900px;">
        <div style="height: 20px;"></div>
        <div id="divcalander"></div>
        </br>
        <div id="statementdiv">
        <h2 id="redstatement">Any event with a red background is a mandatory annual inservice.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the inspection of the month event which is working fine.

```
<td class="fc-event-container">
<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-hasqtip="40" aria-describedby="qtip-40" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
    <div class="fc-content">
        <span class="fc-time">10:30a</span> 
        <span class="fc-title">The Class</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Now here is the inspecting of the listDay view of the same event

```
<tr class="fc-list-item" data-hasqtip="68" aria-describedby="qtip-68" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
<td class="fc-list-item-time ui-widget-content">10:30a</td>
<td class="fc-list-item-marker ui-widget-content">
    <span class="fc-event-dot"></span>
</td>
<td class="fc-list-item-title ui-widget-content">
    <a>The Class</a>
</td>
```

As you can see the a tag on the month event has the background-color red that shows up on the calendar but on the listDay view the the background-color for the tr is not showing up.  I have tried several different things to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your code is different that this fiddle?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 aspectRatio: 1.6,   
 theme: true,
 eventLimit: false,
            timeFormat: 'h:mmt',
        header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,listWeek,listDay,listMonth'
            },
            views:{
                month:{
                    titleFormat: '[MCH In-Sevices for ]'+'MMMM YYYY'
                },
                listWeek:{buttonText: 'List Week'},
                listDay:{buttonText: 'List Day'},
                month:{buttonText: 'Month'},
                listMonth:{buttonText: 'List Month'}
            },
        defaultView: 'month',
  events: [
            
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-12-01T10:30:00',
                end: '2016-12-01T12:30:00',
      backgroundc: 'red'
            },
        {
                title: 'Meeting 2',
                start: '2016-12-01T12:30:00',
                end: '2016-12-01T14:30:00',
      backgroundc: 'green'
            }
        ],
eventRender:function(event,element){
if (event.backgroundc == 'red') {
               element.css('background-color', '#ff0000');
               }
            },


});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5wuop1z0/

Comment: I looked at this closely and the only thing I can find different than yours is in the data. I have an id field and I do not have an end field.  I am going to change my query to put an end field in it and see if that changes it.

Comment: I changed the data, made sure I am using the same versions of jquery and the plug-ins as you were and to no avail. The code matches yours to the letter except for the code source.